# Clearcoat of professionally finished countertop is still not hardening after three months

Tags: countertops, polyurethane, acrylic, refinishing

Has anybody had issues with a poly acrylic coating never hardening?

Our countertops were refinished by the local franchise of a national countertop and bathtub refinishing company. We were on vacation and didn’t use the kitchen for about a month. About a month and a half after the job was completed, I had stacked several heavy plates on the counter. When I picked them up, it felt like the bottom plate was sticking. That’s when I noticed that the bottom plate had left an embossed imprint on the countertop.  I called the company back, and they told me that it wouldn’t fully cure until 60 days. I waited the 60 days, plus about two weeks, and found that the situation has not changed. You can press your fingernail into the counter, and it leaves a mark. If you put something heavy on the counter, it leaves an imprint. The best comparison I can think of is when your socks leave an imprint of the knit pattern on your skin. Like a sock imprint, the imprints in my counter self heal – they go away over time.

The franchise owner is very defensive, yelling and accusing me of misusing the countertop, but I have been very honest with him about exactly what is causing this. The technician who did the work seems baffled. Should I just wait to see if it cures? The technician thinks that the solution is for him to come and apply another layer of clear-coat.

Comment: A fast search seems to say 60 days is much too long for it to dry/cure.

Comment: Applying another coat on top is probably not good.  If the first coat/s are not drying/curing then they must be removed before more coats.

Comment: There probably was not enough hardener put in the  mixture.  It would be almost impossible  to prove that.   It may be time for small claims court.

Comment: Thank you crip659 and RMDman. My spouse and I have been thinking the same thing, so it’s nice to know that credible people agree with us. The owner guy is so defensive and hostile that I really don’t think we will be able to work things out with him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it should not be your responsibility to figure this out. You paid fair money to professionals who had a responsibility to perform quality work.
If this was a "local franchise of a national... company" then you should go above the "defensive and hostile" local franchise owner and contact the parent company about the issue. If they care about their reputation they will step in and either direct the franchise owner to make it right (whatever that requires) or send out a representative to investigate.